# Seemly random "java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation"

Tags: android, android-studio

I've recently updated to Android 2.0 preview 6 (the issue began in preview 5), and since I did, I get random

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation
```

errors. In my investigations, it seems to be a duplicate library issue, but it happens randomly in my code, and at varying locations. I don't have any local libraries, and have gone through my gradle list, and can't find anything off.

If I clean my project, the issue solves itself, but I find myself cleaning it 10+ times a day to fix this. Anyone know what's going on?

**gradle imports:**

```
provided 'com.michaelpardo:ollie-compiler:0.3.2-SNAPSHOT'
androidTestCompile "com.android.support:support-annotations:${APPCOMPAT_VERSION}"
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'
androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test:runner:${ESPRESSO_RUNNER_VERSION}"
androidTestCompile "com.android.support.test:rules:${ESPRESSO_RUNNER_VERSION}"
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0'
compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
compile 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.7.0'
compile 'com.tonicartos:stickygridheaders:1.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'jp.wasabeef:picasso-transformations:1.2.1'
compile 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:1.3.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:logging-interceptor:2.6.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
compile 'com.michaelpardo:ollie:0.3.2-SNAPSHOT'
```

**Full Stack Trace**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                               Process: com.winering.wine, PID: 24395
                                                               java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation
                                                                   at com.winering.wine.activities.connections.ConnectionFragment$$ViewBinder.bind(ConnectionFragment$$ViewBinder.java:8)
                                                                   at butterknife.ButterKnife.bind(ButterKnife.java:319)
                                                                   at butterknife.ButterKnife.bind(ButterKnife.java:279)
                                                                   at com.winering.wine.activities.connections.ConnectionFragment.onViewCreated(ConnectionFragment.java:104)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1106)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:952)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1474)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17515)
                                                                   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
                                                                   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17515)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5380)
                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17515)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5380)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17515)
                                                                   at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:940)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17515)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5380)
                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17515)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5380)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17515)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5380)
                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17515)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5380)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17515)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5380)
                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2567)
                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17515)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2290)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1398)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1597)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1256)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6658)
                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:813)
                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:613)
                                                                at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame
```

Comment: Hi.. I am also facing the same issue using `Reterofit`. I tried **Rebuilding the project**, setting **Scope as Provided in Dependencies in Module Settings** and [this](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/679). These things worked but not permanently. Please let me know if you solved the issue.

Comment: I reverted back to Android Studio 1.5, and haven't had the issue since. No more preview builds for me.